# public ip not working and it has 192.168.30.1 as Gateway

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip

My ISP gave me one public IP, I want to use it for MySQL Server running on one computer which I gave it a static IP, and then did Port Forwarding 3306 to that IP

when I'm inside the network I can access the database remotely via the Public IP (185.136.x.x), but as soon as I connect to another ISP Internet it gives me an error

in the image is the IP details, and when I google what's my ip it gives me the same IP, I'm in doubt with Gateway.. is it ok for gateway to have a private ip?
how to make sure the Public IP works fine, the problem is it's Fiber Optic Network and I can't as you know no computer has GPON port, and I can't find any switch with GPON and Ethernet ports or a converter that converts to ethernet

[Router configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTYlG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the gateway can be anything as long as it's on the same link, since its address is only used to determine the gateway's MAC. (For example, IPv6 routinely uses link-local addresses there.)

You likely won't be able to install your own GPON adapter anyway, as it usually has specific configuration (passwords, etc.), but you *should* be able to reconfigure your router to 'bridge' mode.